# Better implementations for this dynamic program to solve optimization problem?

Tags: dynamic-programming, recursion

In the code below, I describe a problem and provide a backtracking implementation in Python that solves it:

```python
# Find the combination of k out of n measures that maximizes score 
# while ensuring that their total cost does not surpass C.
# Each measure has a profit of m₁, …, mₙ and a cost of d₁, …, dₙ. 
# The score of the ith measure is defind as mᵢ/dᵢ.

K = 4
def max_gain_bounded_cost_rec(M, D, C, k, i):

    if i < 0 or C <= 0 or k == K:
        return(0)

    if D[i] > C:
        return max_gain_bounded_cost_rec(M, D, C, k, i - 1)

    return max(
            max_gain_bounded_cost_rec(M, D, C, k, i - 1),
            max_gain_bounded_cost_rec(M, D, C - D[i], k + 1, i - 1) + M[i]/D[i]
            )
```

I wanted to implement a dynamic programming to practice - I am just learning the topic. To make matters more clear, let us define the recursive function mathematically.

Let $i$ a natural number, $m_1, \ldots, m_n$ and $d_1, \ldots, d_n$ two sequences of real positive numbers, $K$ a positive constant s.t. $K<n$ and $C$ a positive constant. Then the recursive function is

$$
f (i, c, k) = \begin{cases}
0 & i = 0 \lor c \leq 0 \lor k = 0 \\ 
f(i - 1, c, k) & d_i>c \\ 
\max \Big( f(i-1, c, k), \frac{m_i}{d_i} +f(i - 1, c -d_i, k-1) \Big) & otherwise
\end{cases}
$$

It is clear that $f(n, C, K)$ solves the problem. Formulating the function this way makes evident the fact that it uses $3$ arguments: $i, c, k$. This is, it keeps track of an index, the "remaining" cost $c$ that we can afford to pay, and $k$ the number of measures taken so far. Hence, the dynamic programming implementation will use a 3d array to store the values of the functions at different arguments. The 3d array (call it $R$) will be such that $R[a, b, c]$ will have the value of $f(a, b, c)$. This is my Python implementation:

```python
def max_gain_bounded_cost(M, D, C, K):

    n = len(M)
    R = [[[0 for _ in range(K + 1)] for _ in range(C + 1)] for _ in range(n + 1)]

    for i in range(n + 1):
        for j in range(C + 1):
            for q in range(K + 1):
                if i == 0 or j <= 0 or K == 0:
                    R[i][j][q] = 0
                elif D[i - 1] > j:
                    R[i][j][q] = R[i - 1][j][q]
                else:
                    R[i][j][q] = max( 
                                     R[i-1][j][q], 
                                     M[i-1]/D[i-1] + R[i-1][j - D[i-1]][q - 1]
                                     )

    return(R[n][C][K])
```

The function works (it returns the same than its recursive counterpart). For example,

```
print(max_gain_bounded_cost_rec([5, 10, 15, 20], [6, 7, 1, 9], 200, 0, 3))
print(max_gain_bounded_cost([5, 10, 15, 20], [6, 7, 1, 9], 200, 9))
```

returns

```
19.484126984126984
19.484126984126984
```

However, my code seems too dense and clunky. I was wondering whether there is a more efficient and/or elegant way of implementing the dynamic function. I emphasize that I am interested in improvements of *clarity/elegance* as well as *efficiency*! I'm new to dynamic programing and I'm sure this could have been done better.